# Imageprieview showing null

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

this is the main activity code

```
    public class MyTestActivity extends Activity {
        private static final int MAX_PAGES = 10;

        private static final String IMAGE_RESOURCE = null;

        private int num_pages = 1;
        private int image=1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);        

            final ViewPagerParallax pager = (ViewPagerParallax) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pager.set_max_pages(MAX_PAGES);
            pager.setBackgroundAsset(R.raw.building);
            pager.setAdapter(new my_adapter());     
            int i=0;
            for(i=0;i<MAX_PAGES;i++)
            {
            num_pages = Math.min(num_pages+1, MAX_PAGES);
            pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); 
            }

            if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
                image=savedInstanceState.getInt(IMAGE_RESOURCE, R.raw.sanfran);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt("image", image);
            final ViewPagerParallax pager = (ViewPagerParallax) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            outState.putInt("current_page", pager.getCurrentItem());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.home:
                break;      

            case R.id.landmark:
                break;
            case R.id.futureproof:
                break;
            case R.id.luxury:
                break;
            case R.id.theinsidestory:
                break;
            case R.id.floorplan:
                break;
            case R.id.layout:
                break;             

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private class my_adapter extends PagerAdapter {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return num_pages;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                return view == o;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View)object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                View new_view=null;

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                new_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
                ImageView imgPreview=(ImageView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgPreview.setImageResource(R.raw.sanfran);
                container.addView(new_view);
                return new_view;
            }

        }
    }
```

here is
 **main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <com.matthieu.ViewPagerParallax
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to make building.jpg as the background image which will be moving (parallax) for 10 times ,and sanfran.jpg as another image which will sit on the image and will be constant .But my app crashes the moment it starts .I checked in eclipse and found that the value of 
 imgPreview is null(eclipse shows null)

```
ImageView imgPreview=(ImageView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

plz help
thanks

Here is the logcat result

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(7141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141): java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at com.matthieu.MyTestActivity$my_adapter.instantiateItem(MyTestActivity.java:105)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:801)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:930)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1366)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  E/AndroidRuntime(7141):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide logcat error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        new_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
        ImageView imgPreview=(ImageView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); // this line as per you is null
```

this clearly means your layout named "page" is not having any ImageView component named imageView1 in it, so check your layout file once.

Comment: yeah true,it does not have one let me change and see

Comment: thats why its null, just add a imageview there with required name.

Comment: Thanks man but I still dint understood how u got that cz i had added that in my main.xml not in page.xml

Comment: Its simple, you said what was null, I figured out rest, Anyways i saw you have posted your main.xml and thats contains a image view with name u were trying to reference in adapter, thats gave me clue of possible error.

Comment: can u help me in another issue ,
now when i slide both the images are sliding. building.jpg(is the background) and sanfran.jpg is the image displayed above it .

I want that sanfran.jpg to be stationary and building to be moving .
How to do that ,even u can forward me to a tutorial  on that 
any idea ???

Comment: Do one thing, restructure your layout, have a framelayout as your parent, set your static picture there backgound, add pager component as child to framelayout, there you can have this ImageView which changes images based on pressing of button.